# Namespace Confusion in Ruby

Tags: ruby, module

I'm playing with Ruby modules.

This works just fine:

```
module Mod1
  def hello
    "Hello from mod 1"
  end
end

module Mod2
  def hello
    "Hello from mod 2"
  end
end

class Foo
  include Mod1
  include Mod2
end

f = Foo.new
puts f.hello
# output: "Hello from mod 2"
```

This doesn't work:

```
module Mod1
  def hello
    "Hello from mod 1"
  end
end

module Mod2
  def hello
    "Hello from mod 2"
  end
end

class Foo < BasicObject
  include Mod1
  include Mod2
end

f = Foo.new
puts f.hello
# output: in `<class:Foo>': uninitialized constant Foo::Mod1 (NameError)
```

This works:

```
module Mod1
  def hello
    "Hello from mod 1"
  end
end

module Mod2
  def hello
    "Hello from mod 2"
  end
end

class Foo < BasicObject
  include ::Mod1
  include ::Mod2
end

f = Foo.new
puts f.hello
```

Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby's Object model, `Object` is defined underneath the `BasicObject`. So whatever you will be defining in Object wouldn't be accessible from `BasicObject` by default.

```
 Object.superclass # => BasicObject
```

Now your class `Foo` is an subclass of `BasicObject`, so it goes top of the `Object` class. Thus those modules are not visible to the `Foo` class. as the modules `Mod1` and `Mod2` are defined inside the `Object` class. Anything you will be defining in the top level will go the scope of `Object` class, that is how Ruby's top level has been defined.

Your last part of code is working as you explicitly has given the constant path as `include ::Mod1` and `include ::Mod2`. `::Mod2` means you are saying the module is defined in `Object` class, bring it for me here in the class.

But which is not the case for the second part of your code, so `Foo` is unable to find out the modules, as you didn't give it the path, like the above part.

First part is working, as modules are defined in `Object` scope and class `Foo` is a subclass of `Object`, so only `include Mod1` and `` `include Mod2 `` does work as expected.

Here is similar use-cases, which might give you some light on this :

## no error here

```
class B 
    module F;end
end

class A < B
    include F
end
```

## error here

```
class B
  include F
end

class A < B
  module F;end
end
# ~> -:2:in `<class:B>': uninitialized constant B::F (NameError)
# ~>  from -:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The module being inside a class is clear. What I was missing was the concept that everything at the top level is in the `Object` scope. Thanks!